# Excecuting file at startup

Tags: startup, executable

I am trying to start a script at boot and i can't seem to get it to work. I made the file, put it in /etc/init.d, made it executable by `chmod +x file.sh`, and did `update-rc.d file.sh defaults 100`. Is there anything else I need to do?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You may have  to create a symlink to `/etc/rc.d/` :

```
ln -s /etc/init/file.sh /etc/rc.d/
```

Or you can add a line in  `rc.local`

Comment: I created symlink to /etc/rc3.d/ as that is the default runlevel for Ubuntu.

Comment: I think it depends on you version, as I know on ubuntu 14.04 the default  run level is  `/etc/rc2.d/` you check your current run level  by `runlevel`